# Я использую sprintf и после этого malloc перестает выделять память

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, arm

Если не использовать `sprintf` то всё нормально работает.

```
int some_f()
{
    SEGGER_RTT_TerminalOut(2, (char*)modem_data);


    uint8_t  amount = 0;

    char         sep[4]          = "\r\n";
    char         *array[32];
    char         *pstr;


    pstr = strtok((char*)modem_data, sep); //разделяем несколько сообщений друг от друга
    while(pstr != NULL)
    {
        array[amount] = pstr;
        amount++;
        pstr = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    amount--;

    while(amount > 0)
    {
        uint8_t sms_index = 0;
        sms_index = (uint8_t)hex_char(array[amount-2][7]);
        if(strstr(array[amount-2], "REC UNREAD") > 0)   //читаем только непрочитанные
        {

            //char     _str[64];
            char         _sep[5]         = "\",\"";
            char         *_array[32];
            char         *_pstr;
            uint8_t  _amount = 0;
            char       sms_string[125];
            memset(sms_string, 0,   sizeof(sms_string));
            _pstr = strtok(array[amount-2], _sep);
            while(_pstr != NULL)    //разделяем сообщение
            {
                _array[_amount] = _pstr;
                _amount++;
                _pstr = strtok(NULL, _sep);
            }
            _amount--;


            SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "amount = %d\r\n", amount);
            SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "sms_index = %d\r\n", sms_index);
            SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "%s\r\n", array[amount-2]);
            while(_amount)
            {

                SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "%s\r\n", _array[_amount]);
                _amount--;
            }
            SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "%s\r\n", array[amount-1]);

            //_array[2] номер
            //_array[3] время 
            //_array[4] дата
            //array[amount-1] текст

            sprintf(sms_string,"%s %s", _array[2], array[amount-1]);
            mqtt_put("sms", sms_string);
            memset(sms_string, 0,   sizeof(sms_string));
            memset(_array, 0,   sizeof(_array));                                    
        }
            amount-=2;
    }

    memset(array, 0,    sizeof(array));

    at_write("+CMGDA=\"DEL READ\""); //удаляем прочитанные

    return 0;

}   



void mqtt_put(char *topic_name_p, char *content_p)
{
    uint32_t err_code;
    char *content = (char*)malloc((strlen(content_p)+1) * sizeof(char)); //выделяем память под content
    char *topic_name = (char*)malloc((strlen(topic_name_p)+1)* sizeof(char)); //выделяем память под topic_name

    strlcpy(content, content_p, strlen(content_p)+1); //копируем в новое место content
    strlcpy(topic_name, topic_name_p, strlen(topic_name_p)+1);//копируем в новое место topic_name

    mqtt_fifo_t *mqtt_fifo = malloc(sizeof(mqtt_fifo_t)); //выделяем память под структуру   
    mqtt_fifo->content       = content;
    mqtt_fifo->topic_name  = topic_name;
    //помещяем в структуру ссылки на строки

    if(mqtt_fifo != NULL && mqtt_fifo->content !=NULL && mqtt_fifo->topic_name !=NULL) //проверям на было ли ошибок при выделении памяти
    {
        //здесь код который выполняется если всё нормально
    }
    else
    {
        SEGGER_RTT_SetTerminal(1);
        SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "MALLOC ERR"); //Эта функция просто выводит сообщение об ошибке
        SEGGER_RTT_SetTerminal(0);
    }
}
```

До вызова `some_f`, `mqtt_put` работает без каких либо нареканий, но после, `malloc` возвращает нулевой указатель.
Это только один из примеров использования `sprintf` и самый нерациональный но далее используются другие варианты которые также ломают `malloc`.
Далее по ходу вся выделенная память очищается и высвобождается.

Comment: Момент с `sprintf(str, "%s%s", str ,s);` я исправил но это не на что не повлияло.

Comment: Показывайте, на что именно исправили. Сейчас написана чушь, которая даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: Понятно, что этот код просто не компилируется, но я бы хотел сказать, что даже в компилирующемся коде (наверное вы этого в конце-концов добьетесь) перед вызовом `strlen()` надо быть уверенным, что данные в буфере **завершаются нулем** (у вас же и никакого намека нет на инициализацию буфера)

Comment: Окей. Вот кусок рабочего кода который компилируется всё с ним хорошо и который ломается если использовать sprintf  в нем

Comment: @AnT  спасибо исправил. Но это всё равно ничего не решает

Comment: Ну и чему равны `_array[2]` и `array[amount-1]` перед этими  вызовами `sprintf`?

Comment: @AnT Коментарии же есть. Номер и текст

Comment: @наиль аглиев: Тут важны интересуют кокртеные значения. Причем на каждой итерации.

Comment: @Ant Номер телефона 11 цифр в международном формате. Текст сообщения произвольный допустим Hello World. Если непрочитанное сообщение только одно то код с `sprintf` выполняется только один раз и далее только при поступлении нового сообщения

Comment: Если речь об этом `sprintf(sms_string,"%s %s", _array[2], array[amount-1]);`,  то надо быть уверенным, что всегда перед ним в разборах через `strtok()`  `amount` и `_amount` были не меньше 2-х. Иначе `_array[2]` содержит неизвестно какой указатель

Comment: @avp Я уверен что всегда там содержится указатель на существующую строку.

Comment: Что тут скажешь? Отлаживайте. Попечатайте промежуточные результаты, в конце-концов посмотрите отладчиком.

Comment: Side note: С каких пор номер ограничен 11 цифрами?

Comment: @0andriy С тех самых с которых я тестирую это всё.(очевидно что я сам отправляю смс и у меня не 10 симок с которых я бы мог это делать)